# Remove extra bullets on Wordpress page - edit CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to remove the extra bullets on this Wordpress page which uses the PTSC comparison table plugin.

[image: Image showing the extra bullet point]

Below is a link to the page in question

https://www.okkami.com/pages/design-configuration/

I have been trying something like adding the below code to the style.css file, however I am unsure as to what reference to use

```css
.ptsc_comparison_table_feature_titles li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to remove the rounded check bullet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below css so remove it extra bullets

```css
.ptsc_comparison_table .ptsc_comparison_table_feature_values li:before{
  content:none !important;
}
```